# calling powershell script from command line error

Tags: powershell, splunk

when executing the code below from the splunk system we get the following error coming back in the log file:

> ERROR User script exception: : Cannot bind parameter 'FilterScript'. Cannot convert the "Name" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock".

It seems to be not liking the `Name` variable in the `where` clause, is there anyway to get around this?

```
Get-WmiObject –class win32_process |
Add-Member -MemberType ScriptProperty -PassThru -Name Username -Value {$ud= $this.GetOwner();$user=$ud.Domain+"\"+$ud.User;
if ($user -eq "\") {"SYSTEM"} else {$user}}  |
where  Name -eq "splunkd.exe" |
where  Username -ne "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM"  | 
Format-List -Property Name, KernelModeTime, UserModeTime, ProcessID, WorkingSetSize, PageFileUsage, PageFaults
```

Answer (score 1):

You have older version of PowerShell, where `Where-Object` is expecting a code block and tries to treat the `Name` as one. Use this format instead:

```
Where-Object { $_.Name -eq "splunkd.exe" } |
```